# Wine firefox hangs on dns lookup

Tags: wine

Before I start, I absolutely have to use wine and firefox to get access to my cable company video player unless I want to use windows so, no, I am not happy about this but it seems to be my only option right now.

Cannot resolve any addresses on wine firefox 32 bit version.

It just says connecting and there is a wheel turning on the middle of the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but if you're on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libnss-mdns:i386 libnss-resolve:i386
```

Comment: I am still having the problem. I just get a white screen and firefox is almost unresponsive. This is only an issue on the last few releases of firefox. Firefox in wine used to work just fine like 6 months ago.